# How to use custom verb with alamofire?

Tags: swift, xcode, http, methods, alamofire

I want to add two custom verbs "claim" & "bind" in alamofire?

[image]

Comment: Which version are you using? Isn't it https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/HTTPMethod.swift ?

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire will support fully custom HTTP methods in an upcoming update (something after 5.0.0 beta 7). Until then, building your `URLRequest`s manually will allow you to set the method directly, as a `String`. Also, methods are case-sensitive, so be careful.

`request.httpMethod = "claim"`